# vsftpd folder/subfolders permissions

Tags: linux, ftp, filezilla, vsftpd

I have set-up a VSFTPD and it's working, however there is a little problem with the permissions that is acting wierd.

If I access the FTP user I created I can see all folders, subfolders and files inside of them correctly. However unless I give the folder public permission (chmod 777) the folder and It's contents cannot be seen by the FTP client (in this case, filezilla).

As a resume:

- I can create, upload into any folder/subfolder using filezilla
- When I create a folder through filezilla it's permissions are
  "drwx------"
- When I create a folder through server console it's permissions are
  "drwxr-xr-x" and I can access them through filezilla
- I can't access the folder and see It's contents through filezilla,
  but I can through the server console using the same user.

[Filezilla screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kp91.png)

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVLiz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check config and find a setting called something `umask`. it will be `077` currently. Change it to `022`. Now your files and folders created via ftp will have permission `777` - `022` = `755`, so visible to group and others. writeable only to user.